# Key frame locations are all being set to the same location

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm new to blender and I pretty sure I pressed something but I don't what as it was working fine before, but my problem is in the animation. Whenever I set a location for a key frame for any object, then set a new location for a new key frame for where I want the object to move, the newest location become the location for the previously made key frame as it changes it self to the new location.

Interestingly if I make new key frames in between old ones that I had done before this problem arose, they work as before I started having this problem.

I've tried changing the location manually by putting the xyz values for location in the transform (with in object properties) but they just snap back to last value.
I've also tried changing the marker type and interpolation mode but nothing.

Any Help?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a recording of your screen